# How to change values of parameters in PRD

Tags: report, parameter-passing, onchange, pentaho

In a report I set the client then the client's product. The client drop down is populated by a query that returns the client's id and client's name. Then I use the client's id on the second query to return that client's products. It works nicely up until I've selected a client and then a product and I want to change the client. On this case, the product's drop down displays the product query ids for the previous client.

I've googled a bit and found that there's a function to be added on the second parameter's "Post-Processing Formula" field. I've tried using something like that:

```
=IF(HASCHANGED[id_client];[id_product]="")
```

But it didn't work. What's the correct syntax for this? Is there an onchange implementation?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives a syntax error on Report Designer 3.9

`=IF(HASCHANGED[id_client];[id_product]="")`

`HASCHANGED` needs ()

This does not give a sytax error

`=IF(HASCHANGED([id_client]);[id_product]="")`

Answer (score 1):

I am using report designer 3.9.0. I performed a similar test. Both of the parameter's are drop down list and the second parameter automatically gets blank when first parameter has been changed.